# Knowledge Request- Automatically Log Out of Google Services Script

Tags: applescript, safari, automator, gmail, vpn

TL;DR- is there a way to set Gmail to automatically log itself out?

I am in the process of distancing myself from Google's services, and while it is inevitable that one will always interact with Google's services ("Hello, Youtube."), even with certain practices set in place (i.e. using Duck Duck Go's privacy Safari extension, a VPN, remaining logged out of Google's main search page, etc.) I do still need to use Gmail during this transitional period.

Sure, one could log out after using the service, but sometimes I forget. Is there a script that could automate the process of logging out or is there possibly * *gasp* * a setting within Google's preferences?

Comment: Would Using incognito and periodically logging out of all sessions in google settings suffice?

Comment: That is definitely one way of doing it, I’m trying to automate the process though; I’d rather avoid having to manually log out or remember to switch to a Private Browsing window when I need to access Gmail. I have a VPN and use Duck Duck Go’s Privacy extension in Safari so that I can still use Google Search while being logged out and provide them with far less tracking data (Google is still king when it comes to search engines).